# Manage -20 pixels subview when Embed In View

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

What I'm doing in my App?

In the storyboard first I added 3 `UITextFields` 5 `UIButtons` and Etc.
and I forgot to add those controllers inside the `UIView` so what I did.

- I select all those controllers *(`UITextFields` 5 `UIButtons` and Etc)*
- Go to **Editor -> Embed In -> View**

That's was pretty to add `UIView` as super view of selected controllers.

By My question is Embed `UIView` is started with origin **X = -20** and **Y = -20**

1) Why this happing like started with **-20** pixels?
2) And when I resizing `UIView's` origin **-20** to **0** pixel then it also affect to subview's origin ? so how can we resize `UIView` without affect to subview's original size ?

> NOTE: I know that we can manage subview by auto-layout based on superview but I want to manage without use of auto-layout.

Comment: Add x, y constraints relative to it's superview, It should work

Comment: Yeah it will be worked but I want to know answers of mine 2 questions

Comment: Can you share screenshot? what constraints have you applied?

Comment: Actually I have old project and it is not constraints based project So I'm applying constraints to all screen. where I have one ViewController and that has UIScrollView so I'm added UIView inside ScrollView for manage content size of it.

Comment: Provide Top, Bottom, leading, trailing and Center Horizontally constraints to UIView inside ScrollView relative to Superview. It will set your X, Y position to 0.

Comment: @RahulKumar - Thanks to give give quick reply but I want to improve my knowledge thats why asking question otherwise I know how to mange It by auto-layout . Do you know manage it without auto-layout ? and ans of 1) Why this happing like started with -20 pixels?
2) And when I resizing UIView's origin -20 to 0 pixel then it also affect to subview's origin ? so how can we resize UIView without affect to subview's original size ?